# Display elements in dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day community,

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 project, where on edit page I'm use jquery script. But I have a problem to display elements on the page.

Here is my dropdown's HTML markup before changes:

```
<select id="ProgramId" name="ProgramId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">testrtu1</option>
    <option value="2">testrtu2</option>
    <option value="3">testtsi</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">testrtu3</option>
</select>
```

And here is after jquery changes

```
<select id="ProgramId" name="ProgramId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">testrtu1</option>
    <option value="2">testrtu2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">testrtu3</option>
</select>
```

But it's display on the page not a selected element `testrtu3`, always display first element. And when I click save button saved my first value.

Here is my `jQuery` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var values = [];
    $(".checkboxUniversities:checked").each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/' + values, function (data) {
        alert('Return json result new information');
        var items = '<option disabled>Select a Program</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, program) {
            items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $('#ProgramId').html(items);
    });
    //var selectedElement = $("#ProgramId").find(":selected").text();
});
```

I guess I need somehow add selected value when create my `dropdown` inside `jquery`, or after creating, but I don't know how. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before appeding options to your dropdown you have to save `selected index` or `text` in variable and use it further.

**Sample Code:**

```
<select id="ProgramId" name="ProgramId"><option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">testrtu1</option>
    <option value="2">testrtu2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">testrtu3</option>
</select>
<input id="click" type="button" value="click me"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var option = '<option value="1">testrtu1</option><option value="2">testrtu2</option><option value="3">testtsi</option><option  value="4">testrtu3</option>';
    $("input#click").click(function(){
        var selInx = $("select[name='ProgramId'] option:selected").index();
    $('#ProgramId').html(option);
        $('select#ProgramId').prop('selectedIndex', selInx);
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fQV62/)**</kbd>

**NOTE:** As we cannot connect to your backend code to get options hardcoded in code itself and on click of button dropdown will be replaced with latest options and will update the selected index based on first one. You can use either `selectedindex` or `text` based on your requirement.